# Record mouse click coords

Tags: java, php, javascript, mysql

I've searched around and couldn't find anything that really helped much on this.

I'm trying to make a script that records the coordinates of mouse click's that have the coordinate 0 in it so for example x=0 y=125 NOT X=100 y=125
And when it detects coords like that I want it to add them to my mysql database like this.

Username - the user who hit the coord

x - x coordinate

y - y coordinate

amount - how many times they hit that coord

Anyone think they could help me with this?

Updated with code.

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.map').click(function(e){
        alert('x pos: ' +  e.pageX + ';  y pos: ' + e.pageY + ';'); 
        if(e.pageX == 0 || e.pageY ==0){
            <?php
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO clickmap (id) VALUES ('".$_SESSION['username']."')")
     or die(mysql_error());  
?>
        }
    }); 
}); 

</script>
```

Comment: have you written any attempts?

Comment: Reminds me of autohotkey , tho I know that's not it..

Comment: I've only created the database, I have no idea how to do this myself, I'm pretty new to coding. I'll be using this as part of a macro detection.

Comment: Hum, so will you use Swing or is it going to be a background process that captures where the mouse is, independently of the application that the user is using at the moment?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure what you mean I have an php based online browser game I'm making, and I need it to tell me if they hit the 0 coord because of a commonly used macro tool that causes that coord to show up

Comment: What you want is a javascript script (maybe jquery) which detect the mouse clicks, and if matching the constraints, send an ajax request to your server to log the click. But this will be not very scalable, so your game will need to be mostly client side, and have the clicks sent in batch if you still need to log them server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A jquery solution (assuming someones using a browser) would be to bind a click event to the thing you want to listen to, then use the event that triggered's pageX and pageY like so:

```
if(e.pageX == 0 || e.pageY == 0) {
//do stuff.  
}
```

this is a working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/XdLJ9/

Comment: Nvm did that on my own Thanks again!